# Where can I find the "restorecount" value macOS uses to track open windows and reset it?

Tags: macos, user-account, window-manager

1. In *System Preferences* uncheck `General > Close windows when quitting an app
2. Open *TextEdit.app*
3. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for a *New* file
4. Quit *TextEdit.app*
5. In Finder go to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.TextEdit.savedState/` we'll be looking for a file here shortly
6. Open *TextEdit.app*
7. Quickly, open the file `restorecount.plist` that has appeared in Finder
8. Look at the `end` value

Currently, on my macOS installation, `end` has a value of 570214618 which, as I understand it, means that since whatever epoch — a long time ago in an operating system far, far away — there have been over 570 million "windows" opened on my Mac. The value is shared across all user accounts. 10 months ago, that number was 544 million on my system according to this old question of mine: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320967/15281

The effect of this is that, for some apps, there is a noticeable (4 to 5 seconds) delay whilst they do something before their restored windows appear. My workaround, see the above linked question, is to turn off window saving for those specific apps. But I'd rather not have to do that.

So, I'd like to reset the `restorecount` value at its source. Does anybody know where it is stored and/or how can I reset it?

Comment: Why are you so sure restorecount is what's causing this problem? Do you have any evidence other than "this number is high, and some programs are taking a long time to open, ergo they must be related?" Because, that logic by itself seems super tenuous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `end` value is not the number of windows you have opened, it is a [Cocoa timestamp](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate). `570214618` corresponds to `January 26, 2019 4:56:58 PM GMT`. As far as I can tell, the purpose of `restorecount.plist` is just to track how long it takes to restore the windows.

For apps that are taking a long time to start, you can try cleaning out their saved application state and see if that helps, but there are lots of other reasons an app might take a long time to start. The most common reason an app takes a long time to start is that it needs a lot of memory and you are already using all the available RAM so some memory needs to be compressed or written to disk in order to free up memory for the app. You can get a sense of this by looking at the "memory pressure" in the Activity Monitor.

You can also look at the amount of Swap Used (also in Activity Monitor). If that number goes up when you launch an app, then not having enough free memory is definitely a source of delay.

Comment: Great spot on `end` being the timestamp! I should have realised that. The apps I am using are very small, one window apps and after deleting their restore state, with my usual system memory pressure of about 20% I see the delay. But I'll investigate some more.

Comment: @MattSephton please accept the answer and award the bonus

Comment: Of course, my pleasure